# Woocommerce category ACF field not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

First of all I'm saying this is not a duplicated question i tried other answers but not worked.

I added ACF field to woocommerce category and i need to shows that on woocommerce category archive pages.

Below shows how i add ACF

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1859170/1fb3dc839dff36c92d4ee52f5167ca78

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1859175/1d1e43f70ae925ac5501f9e360f4a463

It shows on product category admin area

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1859197/c5df7d20319c73d94896058daa6f3f2a

But when i tried to shows on category page on fronted it not showing,

```
<?php
$queriedObject=get_queried_object();
echo get_field('categoryslider','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
?>
```

Above code i got from stack overflow, i also tried other few solutions but it didn't worked, I'm using latest versions of all plugins.

can anyone help me please. Thank You

Answer (score 6):

As the document said: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/, you have three ways to get the field value.

Here is my test:

```
//It works
$queriedObject = get_queried_object();
echo get_field('categoryslider','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);

//not working, Added in version 5.5.0
$queriedObject = get_queried_object();
echo get_field('categoryslider','term_'.$queriedObject->term_id);

//It works!
$queriedObject = get_queried_object();
echo get_field('categoryslider', $queriedObject);
```

Comment: It's very strange non of above worked, the other acf fields on products are working fine, only issue with product category field ACF, i'm not sure why is that